# Getting the correct frame inside willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, layout, rotation, orientation, autoresize

My subviews have different layout when in portrait and landscape orientation.
The layout is based on the frame of the superview, and is not trivial (can't be achieved using autoresizing springs and struts).

The problem is that if i'm changing the frame of the subViews during willRotateToInterfaceOrientation, the animation is correct, but the frame is the superView is still the frame from the old orientation.

If i'm changing the subViews during didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation, the frame is the superView is indeed the correct one, but the frame change only occurs after the rotating animation and it doesn't look good.

What is the correct way to change the frames of the subViews when changing orientation?

Comment: I solved this problem by writing a method in each subview that will handle frame change part. I will set parent view's frame in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and then generate a new similar frame using CGFrameMake function and pass it to each subView. It worked for me....check if it is helpful.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer. In willRotateToInterface i still don't know the frame of the superView because the rotation didn't happen yet. This is the problem.

Comment: I do not use superView's frame to rotate subviews. I calculate what would be value for superView's frame after rotation and then make a new CGRect based on calculation and then pass that to handleOrientation method of each subView. If you are not able to calculate what would be value for superView's frame after rotation then above will not work for you.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately i can't calculate what would be the frame of the superView after the rotation.

Comment: can you give any clue about what kind of content you view will have? without that i would be difficult to suggest anything.

Comment: Actually Akshay's answer was what i was looking for. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try overriding `layoutSubviews`. There you can layout the subviews in accordance with the current orientation, without bothering about will/did RotateFromInterfaceOrientation. `layoutSubviews` is called every time the views are laid out. This shall help you in timing your frame changes with the animation.

Comment: But it will mean that i'm moving all the layout logic to the View and not the ViewController. Currently I'm setting the layout of the subView according to properties of the UIViewController. Moving the logic to UIView means that i have to subclass UIView and move all the parameters to this custom subClass. I'm not completely sure that this logic should be in the UIView and not the UIVIewController, but i'll try.

Answer (score 4):

This function works for what you need because the views frame has changed from the rotation and it doesn't stall the custom animation.

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    float width = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation) ? [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width : [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height;
//do something with the width now
//or you can get the height the same way
}
```